# What is the easiest, simplest way to resolve WMI/WBEM javascript blocking by Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activexobject

I have developed multiple JavaScript Functions that utilize "control = new ActiveXObject."  All of these functions work perfectly without issue when the javascript involves commonly used plugins such as Acrobat Reader, Flash, QuickTime, etc.  When I move beyond the realm of ActiveXObject and plugins into "new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");" the javascript is blocked by Internet Explorer unless I lower my Internet Explorer Security Settings.  It is my understanding the only way around this issue is to use signed scripts involving a certificate from Comodo or similar certificate authority.  Since I am only interested in functionality within Internet Explorer, it is my understanding that I need to use an Authenticode certificate.  I am of the understanding that Authenticode does in fact authenticate java within Internet Explorer.  Personally, I would rather not have to use signed scripts for "new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");" but perhaps this is my only available option.

a.  If there is a quicker and easier way around this issue that does not involve lowering Security Settings within Internet Explorer, I would be very much interested to know what tha would be.  It doesn't appear that I can prompt the browser/user to allow execution of a javascript that involves ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator").

b.  If I am understanding the actual solution to this issue, is my understanding of Authenticode and javascript correct?  Does Authenticode authenticate the execution of javascript within Internet Explorer?

c. I would rather not re-invent the wheel and would like to stay in javascript.  It is my understanding that I can place my .js into a .jar.  When I use the following "script archive="helloworld.jar" src="helloworld.js" on a local HTML page, the script runs fine.  When I try to run this same HTML from the internet/server, Internet Explorer prevents it from running.  Are .jar's also automatically blocked by Internet Explorer?  Or am I using the wrong code?  I understand that classes are normally placed in .jar's but do not understand entirely why a simple helloworld using helloworld.jar would run locally but not on internet/server.

Another idea - would using SSL/HTTPS for the entire domain avoid this issue?

Comment: I never considered putting JavaScript in a Java ARchive before..